# Setup run configuration in WebStorm, AngularJS to compile SCSS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, sass, webstorm

I'm trying to debug an AngularJS application in WebStorm using twitter bootstrap SCSS
What happens is when I Run Index.html in WebStorm it doesn't include main.css(it can't find it) because it is in .tmp folder.
When I run 
    `grunt serve` it works just fine because bower reads and includes .tmp folder to behave like styles folder.
How do I setup WebStorm, so it will also be picked up?
What kind of Run Configuration am I supposed to create in WebStorm?
Should I use "Add Watcher" as well?

To reproduce run this:
    `yo angular`
    `[?] Would you like to use Sass (with Compass)? Yes
[?] Would you like to include Twitter Bootstrap? Yes
[?] Would you like to use the Sass version of Twitter Bootstrap? Yes`

And try to use it with Webstorm to run this build succesfully without using `grunt serve`

**Update**
I no longer use Angular nor Grunt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shouldn't use yeoman watchers along with WebStorm watchers.

you should add in before task `grunt compass` - this will create `.tmp` files and build css

checkout JetBrains videos showing how to setup WebStorm with grunt
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8KIir6EsFPE